# How to send Date of birth to Database from html form

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a "job application" form where users get to apply for jobs that are displayed on the website. Everything is working correctly except the date of birth and upload CV (will work on that later). How do I send the DOB to the Database?

I tried adding echo(date) just for the sake of testing even though I know it's incorrect.

what should I add in the   to send the dob to the DB?

```
$fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
$email = $_POST['mobile'];
$mobile = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
$expYears = $_POST['expYears'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$whyHire = $_POST['whyHire'];
$uploadCV = $_POST['uploadCV'];
$dateApplied = $_POST['dateApplied'];


$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$db->insert('users',array('fullName'=>$fullName,'email'=>$email, 'mobile'=>$mobile,
            'dob'=>$dob, 'degree'=>$degree, 'expYears'=>$expYears, 'position'=>$position,
            'whyHire'=>$whyHire, 'uploadCV'=>$uploadCV, 'dateApplied'=>$dateApplied));  // Table name, column names and respective values
$res = $db->getResult();
print_r($res);

if($res) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/Rocket/careers.php");
    die();
} else {
    echo "query error";
}
```

It should POST the date of birth to the database.

Comment: what should I add in the Select > option element to send the dob to the DB?

Comment: is the dob in the database a DATETIME or a DATE field?

Comment: Ok so what format is the date in? Show us the result of this `echo $_POST['dob'];`

Comment: The format is Date and the format is 0000-00-00 (y-m-d)

Comment: Usually why people will give their time of birth to any service provider? @sietse85 it should be just DATE right?

Comment: You should just be able to add it to your insert array. Just verify that the date you're inserting is in the correct format.

Comment: can you show html form to see what is the mistake ? dob should be `TIMESTAMP`, why timespamp, it's universal for mysql db date and avoid date format conflit

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/xj2c5mv7/

Comment: `dobDay`, `dobMonth`, `dobYear` ARE NOT GOING TO BE RETURNED in `$_POST['dob']`

Comment: Which also goes towards emphasising that you should be **checking the inputs exists before using them** and **validating there content as well**

Comment: About the Attacks I am still learning PHP since I am new to backend. So I will worry about the security stuff later. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a date in MYSQL via a string it has to have a specific format.

For a date the string can have the following format:

```
$dob = "2000-01-31"; //what mysql expects
```

But for this to work you have to validate the date that was beeing entered by the user. Since there are so many options it is recommended to use a `date` input field.

```
<input type="date" name="dob" />
```

But since this is not friendly search for a "javascript birthdate script" on google.

Comment: OK, I changed the Select element to input type date. and it worked. 
https://imgur.com/a/AJusB2Y

I thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Please change "dob" datatype as Varchar. This will solve the problem

Comment: thats not good, since it will be harder to use mysql date functions with this field. DATE is the correct field.

Comment: To prevent all the problems related to data type. varchar is the easiest way to prevent errors

Comment: And the easiest way to complicate the normally simple use of a DATE column in simple SQL